# I'm traveling to oman on turkish airlines, do i have to get a turkish visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, turkey

I'm a Yemeni citizen with a Canadian permanent resident, and flying through turkey from Canada to Oman. Do I need a turkish visa? Note: I'm traveling with my Husband and three children who are all Canadian citizens.